# How to trigger and display a flash message without refreshing the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a helper method in my application controller that check to see when an object has been created. Basically if the total number of objects changes it alerts you on the page load with a flash message. This code works fine, but what I want to do is eliminate the need to reload.

How would this be done? I understand the solution would likely involve AJAX, but I'm a newbie to AJAX and rails so I'm not sure how to go about this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not fully clear when you want this message to show. Do you want it to show *you*, for example, when *I* create a new object? That requires either polling (via ajax) or some sort of push notification.

Comment: I want it to display a flash message when the object has been created. Basically I have code that checks to see if the number of objects has changed, and if it does, display a flash message. I want to run this code every 10 seconds or so and display a flash message if the number of objects has changed.

Comment: Sounds like you want an ajax poller, which is almost always simpler to integrate into an existing system than push notifications. What version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3. 3.2 I believe, I'm not on my dev computer at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = setInterval( "checkObjectCount()", 10000 );

  function checkObjectCount() {
    count = <%= @object_count %>;

    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/request_object_count',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data > count) {
          $('#alert_container').show();
          clearInterval(i);
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? If I understand the script, it's polling a url using ajax every 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes, it's calling the function every 10 seconds. In your Rails routes, you would create a route for "ajax/request_object_count", and this page will render the object count. In the ajax call, after the URL has been _success_fully requested, the values would be compared. If true, your alert container would be shown, and the setInterval function would be cleared (stopped). Otherwise, the loop continues.